# Access Device Storage files like music photos etc in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, folder-access

I want to make a music player which will play the music from device's music gallery, in Xamarin Forms.. i couldnt find a way to access storage folders.
I tried `PCLStorage` but i think its not made to access that storage.

Comment: each platform provides specific APIs for accessing their music library - you cannot simply do this via file access